# Забиндить команду

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

я работаю со старым языком **PAWN** и собираюсь оптимизировать его для себя в VS Code.
Мне требуется забиндить одну "компилирование кода" на кнопку F5, я не понимаю, как именно это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста, вот код бинда:

```
[  
    { "key": "f5", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" }  
]
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно настроить Build task: [Customize build and debug tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), [Integrate with External Tools via Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849230/2752075